# Highlight with alert in math mode and diffcoeff (incompatibility with TeX Live 2023)

Tags: diffcoeff

I would like to highlight the each term of the sum **only** with `\alert` command, but with TeX Live 2023 is not working. Let's look the below code.

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

    \alert{
        \[ \dl\alpha+\dl\beta \]
    }

    % Do not work in TeX Live 2023 or later
    \[ \alert{\dl\alpha}+\alert{\dl\beta} \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is the end of the log file.

```tex
! Incompatible glue units.
\reset@color ->\beamer@lastskip =\lastskip 
                                           \edef \beamer@lastskiptexta {\the...
l.13 \end{frame}
              
?
```

- beamer 2023/02/20 v3.69
- diffcoeff 2023/01/24 v5.2
- LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (`lualatex --version`)

Thanks

Comment: The command `\dl` has changed between TL2021 and TL2022.

Comment: try with an additional pair of braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround in the meantime is to add a second pair of braces when `\alert` is used inside math delimters. The following compiles on my (MiKTeX) system:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

    \alert{
        \[ \dl\alpha+\dl\beta \]
    }

    % add a second pair of braces
    \[ \alert{{\dl\alpha}}+\alert{{\dl\beta}} \]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have just uploaded to CTAN version 5.3 of `diffcoeff` which takes care of this issue.

Comment: Thank you very much @andrew-parsloe